# Angular Search for value in JSON and display corresponding data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-services

What i am trying to do is simple. A user enters a value, on button click, my JS calls a service to retreive my JSON data and perform a search on the value entered against the JSON and if a match is found, display the 'Owner'.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="enteredValue">
        </br>
        <button type="button" ng-Click="findValue(enteredValue)">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, getDataService) {   

    $scope.findValue = function(enteredValue) {     
        alert("Searching for = " + enteredValue);

        $scope.MyData = [];

        getDataService.getData(function(data) {

            $scope.MyData = data.SerialNumbers;

        });
    }

});

angular.module('myApp', []).factory('getDataService', function($http) {
    return {
        getData: function(done) {
            $http.get('/route-to-data.json')
            .success(function(data) { 
                done(data);
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                alert('An error occured');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**My JSON:**

```
{
    "SerialNumbers": {
        "451651": [
            {
                "Owner": "Mr Happy"
            }
        ],
        "5464565": [
            {
                "Owner": "Mr Red"
            }
        ],
        "45165": [
            {
                "Owner": "Mr Sad"
            }
        ],
        "4692": [
            {
                "Owner": "Mr Green"
            }
        ],
        "541": [
            {
                "Owner": "Mr Blue"
            }
        ],
        "D4554160N": [
            {
                "Owner": "Mr Loud"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/7bB6A/

I am able to call my service, and retrieve the data from the JSON, but i am stuck on how to perform a search on my retrieved data against the value entered.

Thanks

---

**UPDATE:**

The following finds a serialnumber entered:

```
angular.forEach($scope.MyData, function(value, key) {
            if (key === enteredValue) {
                console.log("I Found something...");
                console.log("Serial: " + key);
                console.log("Owner: " + key.Owner);
            }

        })
```

I can display the found serialNumber via `console.log("Serial: " + key);` but trying to display the Owner as `console.log("Owner: " + key.Owner);` is showing as *Undefined*.

Comment: Should be `console.log("Owner: " + key[0].Owner)` given your data structure

Comment: @MarcKline - Thanks, i've tried the above (for serial 451651).. And in my console.log, i receive Undefined

Comment: Sorry, yes, my mistake. It should be `console.log("Owner: " + value[0].Owner);`: [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/452nFDmxnCROsM4m4Ylf?p=preview)

Comment: @MarcKline - That works! Thanks; the last part of the question was how to display the matched Owner to the front-end HTML?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key is just to iterate over the data object while observing the correct structure for accessing the values.

Your search function could look like this:

```
$scope.results = [];
$scope.findValue = function(enteredValue) {     
    angular.forEach($scope.myData.SerialNumbers, function(value, key) {
        if (key === enteredValue) {
            $scope.results.push({serial: key, owner: value[0].Owner});
        }
    });
};
```

Notice that I'm pushing the results into an array. You can setup an ng-repeat in the view which will use this to present a live view of the results:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="enteredValue">
<br>
<button type="button" ng-Click="findValue(enteredValue)">Search</button>
<h3>Results</h3>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="result in results">Serial number: {{result.serial}}
    | Owner: {{result.owner}}</li>
</ul>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/452nFDmxnCROsM4m4Ylf?p=preview)