# Ionic search bar

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've 3 jsons files linked with 3 controllers, and I need to search on them using ionic/angularjs. I would like the results appear as dropdown menu, like Facebook search or like here in Stackoverflow.

Thank you.

Comment: Great. So what have you tried? SO isn't a code writing service, so first attempt to write what you need, then return if you have a _specific_ problem that you need help with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two things here that you want to do:

- Be able to search inside JSON file, I think you can do that, there is a SO thread for same : [Angular Search for value in JSON and display corresponding data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077526/angular-search-for-value-in-json-and-display-corresponding-data)
- Display an Auto-complete drop-down, I think there bunch  of directives out there, like: https://www.versioneye.com/javascript/sn0opr:ionic-autocomplete/0.1

You can also check following Ionic forum thread for type ahead recommendation:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/recomendation-for-a-typeahead-widget/55

If you want to create your own have look at following tutorial:

http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-typeahead-widget-with-angularjs/

Comment: Thank you so much, that is all what I need